# Ruby ActiveRecord query_cache not being cleared after saved change to a model (upgrade active record 5 to 6)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

After updating the active-record gem from 5 to 6 there were lot of failing specs related to the models not being refreshed even if there were a process that calls .save in the model and updates its data.
I couldn't find any documentation on how the query_cache gets cleared and if that behavior changed in the version but found nothing on the Changelog.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from the [Rails Guides about caching](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sql-caching):

> Query caching is a Rails feature that caches the result set returned by each query. If Rails encounters the same query again for that request, it will use the cached result set as opposed to running the query against the database again.
>
> [...]
>
> The second time the same query is run against the database, it's not actually going to hit the database. The first time the result is returned from the query it is stored in the query cache (in memory) and the second time it's pulled from memory.
>
> However, it's important to note that query caches are created at the start of an action and destroyed at the end of that action and thus persist only for the duration of the action. [...]

That means Ruby on Rails caches those queries for the duration of a request and deletes them at the end of the request. This behavior exists for a long time already, for example, here are the docs of [Ruby on Rails 3.2](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.0/caching_with_rails.html#sql-caching).

Perhaps, if you shared some example code demonstrating your problem, we would be able to provide more detailed answers why your code is failing after the upgrade.

Comment: but then when the cache gets invalidated, I tried the update method and it does invalidate the cache

Comment: I would not expect the `update` method to clear the cache. Simply for the reason that you already have the updated instance in memory. To my knowledge (without being able to point to code) the cache is cleared at the end of the current web request.

Comment: @sel_space it appears you can manually clear the query cache using [`ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::QueryCache#clear_query_cache`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/QueryCache.html#method-i-clear_query_cache). While I have not attempted this it should be executable as `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.clear_query_cache` but you can also call `reload(true)`. More options can be found [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb)

Comment: thanks @engineersmnky, but since the only change I made was upgrading activerecord from 5 to 6 forcing a reload will not be an option for as I have to do it in the entire code base, and might miss some cases that are not covered by tests. I wanted to know what changed in AR that causes this issue to happen.
In my case is different from the instance variable, ie in the controller I save the object and then there is a process in a helper that fetches the same model from the DB, it gets the stale data from the cache and not the newly up to date from the db

Comment: @sel_space then you should update the post or post a new question to show the actual implementation. This process seems a bit awkward and maybe we can help resolve the underlying issue to make this *more* future proof.